# Having trouble installing numpy on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, numpy, debugging

At first, I was trying to install evo (a package for SLAM research) from source and I encountered an error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

So then I tried to install numpy using `pip install numpy`. However I encountered another error:
**SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.**

Finally, I tried to install python-dev using `sudo apt-get install python-dev`, and I found out it has been installed already. So I don't know where the problem is.

My default python version is 3.8.16

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and try again.

If it doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install pypy-dev` instead of python-dev.

You can also try `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it by installing in a virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

maybe [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) could install it?

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

it isn't generally ideal to mix conda and pip, but it should still install numpy successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed miniconda, and run `pip install numpy` in a newly created virtual environment. And it worked !